# AngularJS $scope undefined in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Another AngularJS noob needing a little insight from others.

I have a controller (staffRenewalsController) that basically defines what to do when a user clicks on a table row to edit it handled by $scope.editRow.

It is supposed to present a modal dialog box using $uibModal which works find and present two buttons (Save and Cancel).

**PROBLEM:**  *Save() has $scope available while Cancel() has $scope undefined.  I tried many things over the last few days and I'm not sure why Cancel() has $scope undefined.  I renamed Save() to something arbitrary and it still has $scope available to it.*

Can someone look at my abbreviated code below and shed some light on what I'm doing wrong please?

```
        app.controller('staffRenewalsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', '$uibModal' , 
            function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants, $uibModal) {

            $scope.editRow = function(grid, row) {
                if(row.entity){
                    debugger
                    $scope.selectedRow = row.entity;
                    $scope.selectedRowBackup = $scope.selectedRow;
                    var renewalNumber = '';
                    renewalNumber += row.entity.RenewalNo;
                    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: true,
                        templateUrl: '@Url.Action("View")' + '?renewalNumber=' + renewalNumber,
                        controller: myCommuteStaffRenewalSingleModalController,
                        size: 'lg',
                        scope: $scope,
                        resolve: {
                            items: function () {
                                debugger
                                return $scope.items;

                            }                                ,

                        }
                    });
                }
            }


        var myCommuteStaffRenewalSingleModalController = function($scope, uiGridConstants, $uibModal, $http, $uibModalInstance, items) {

        debugger
            $scope.selectedRecord = $scope.$parent.selectedRow;


            debugger
            $scope.save = function () {
                debugger;

                // $scope is present

            };



            $scope.cancel = function () {
                debugger;

                // $scope is undefined...why?

                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

        };
```

Comment: It looks like your brackets aren't closed in proper order. I'm pretty sure there's a closing bracket missing at line 6.

Comment: What is `myCommuteStaffRenewalSingleModalController` for and why is your `myTableController` defined within it? Also, what's up with that comma after the `items` resolve property?

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to remove code that wasn't relevant and rename variables to obscure their real names for company reasons. I miscopied and I have corrected that now. It does run properly with no errors reported in Chrome.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular Bootstrap Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has a good example of what you're trying to do.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  size: size,
  appendTo: parentElem,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $ctrl.items;
    }
  }
});
```

Notice the controller value is in **quotes** `controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'`.
I would give this a try.

Comment: OP is using a defined function for the modal controller. Using a string simply fetches the controller by name from the injector but this is clearly not the case here.